# Using both displaylink and the HDMI output on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dell XPS 15 9550

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I've decided to switch my setup from Windows to Ubuntu for a while.

I have a Dell XPS 15, with three monitors attached. One via the HDMI port, one via USB-C and a third via DisplayLink (using a plugable dock). On Windows, this all works fine.

I have installed [the official Ubuntu DisplayLink driver](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu), [following the instructions on the site.](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu)

My issue is that, when the DisplayLink monitor is attached, the HDMI/USB-C ones don't work at all. Disconnect the DisplayLink monitor, and the HDMI/USB-C ones are fine.

I tried switching to Wayland, but it doesn't work with DisplayLink at all.

I can live without the third monitor, but is that really living?

Does anybody have any advice on getting all three monitors to work? Is this just not possible currently with DisplayLink on Ubuntu?

Thanks